# Styling part of a (submit) button-label

Tags: html, button

I have a [submit button](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/RdzVd/1/) which is simply marked up as this:

```
<input type='submit' name='foo' value='Continue ⇢' class='button' />
```

[image]

I would like to make the rightward dotted arrow a tad larger.

```
<input type='submit' name='foo' value='Continue <span class='makemeatadlarger'>⇢</span>' class='button' />
```

is obviously not working... Is there a simple way to do this (I am not interested in adding tons of outher divs/spans and preferable without having to use images)

**UPDATE**
Inspired by accepted answer below I came up with this:

**html**

```
<button type='submit' name='foo' value='Continue' class='button'>Continue</button>
```

**css**

```
.button:after  {
    content: ' ⇢';
    font-size: 220%;
    height: 26px;
    margin-top: -19px;  
    float: right;
}
```

**example**

[image]

And heres a [live example over at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/RdzVd/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so because taking the `span` out takes it out of the button. The best way would be a `button` instead of an `input` like so: `<button type="submit" name="foo" class="button">Continue <span class='makemeatadlarger'>⇢</span></button>`

Comment: Perfect, this is what I were looking for. Take a look at my updated code (still needs some work ofcourse): http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/RdzVd/3/

Answer (score 0):

You must style the button text as a whole, not just a portion. To achieve your desired effect wouldn't it be much easier to create an image?

Comment: "preferable without having to use images"

Comment: Yes maybe its the only solution to add a background arrow. Were hoping that some kind of css pseudo element could be used here.

Comment: @Endophage he did say "Is there a simple way to do this"... and an image would be the easiest. Would also get around cross-browser compatibility issues trying to style the button.